# Javascript function not defined SVG element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, electron

I have a svg with say just rect element in it which has inline javascript function call on click.
I have embedded svg in my html (electron based) using object tag.
The problem is if I write javascript outside svg which has to be called on clicking rect element in svg it does not find the function defined instead throws an error saying function is not defined.
But if I paste the same script inside svg tag it works fine.

Why the script written outside svg scope is not able to be found ?

html

```
<object class="svg" id="show-sld" data="sld_old.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
```

svg with inline javascript function call

```
<svg>
<rect style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0;" id="some-id" onclick="openDialog()"/>
</svg>
```

javascript

```
function openDialog(){
#do something
}
```

Works well if I paste the above script inside svg but that is not what I am looking for.
Need to bring javascript outside svg tag. How to achieve this ?

Comment: top.openDialog (or parent). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top

Comment: can you answer with how to call top.openDialog() from inline ? Do I need to set top as javascript variable as window.top ?

Comment: Thanks Robert Longson. It works.

Comment: Lovely, you can write an answer now.

Comment: Works in [codepen](https://codepen.io/Keldfsdf/pen/abLdRQY?editors=1111) pretty well. You can write js code wherever you want and call required function wherever you need: in `svg` tag, in `rect` tag, in `circe` tag, or even wrap it in a `div`.

Comment: mr.boris, you have just used svg as direct dom. I have used svg inside object element tag. In that case it wont find the function.

Comment: anyways am writing the answer based on robert longson comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Am writing the problem statement and answer based on the comments.

svg searches for function inside its own scope. In order to make svg look through the entire dom just add top.functionCall() where top is the topmost window in the window hierarchy

The solution is

```
<svg>
<rect id="some-id" onclick="top.openDialog()"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Added info* to [Vimalan E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70251088/11766145)`s answer

```
<svg>
<rect id="some-id" onclick="top.openDialog()"/>
</svg>
```

If this is run directly in the browser eg(***C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/file_name.html***) it may create an error that the function is not defined.

Put it in server and check eg(***http://localhost/file_name.html***)

Function can be written not only on top, can be wrritten any where in the html page

This works